# Vimeo API C# - Uploading a video

Tags: vimeo-api

I'm following the api's guide about resumable uploads.
I managed to get a response after step 1 ("create the video"),
with a uri and a upload_link.
About the second part, things are not as clear.
It only says which headers should I sent, but there are two things I don't get, 
first - where do I need to put the "upload_link"?
Should the call be like this:

**/me/{upload_link}**? (of course im also adding the access token, etc)

second, what about the actual file? I guess i should send it in the same method, but how? No word about it.

This is the code for the PATCH request:

```
    public string UploadPatch(
string uploadlink,
string method)
{
var headers = new WebHeaderCollection()
{

{ "Tus-Resumable", "1.0.0" },
{ "Upload-Offest", "0" }

};
method = method.ToUpper();


string body = "";
string contentType = "application/offset+octet-stream";

return Helpers.HTTPUpload(uploadlink, method, headers, body, contentType);

}
```

And HTTPUpload():

```
public static string HTTPPatch(string url, string method,
      WebHeaderCollection headers, string payload,
      string contentType)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        if (Proxy != null) request.Proxy = Proxy;

        request.Headers = headers;
        request.Method = method;
        request.Accept = "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json; version=3.1";
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload))
        {
            var streamBytes = Helpers.ToByteArray(payload);
            request.ContentLength = streamBytes.Length;
            Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(streamBytes, 0, streamBytes.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse());
        Debug.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

        var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();

        response.Close();

        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Response from URL {0}:", url), "HTTPFetch");
        Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer, "HTTPFetch");
        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `upload_link` is the URL where you upload the video to. In other words, make your call to the `https://[...].cloud.vimeo.com/upload?[...]` URL instead of the `https://api.vimeo.com` host that is used for other API requests.

Additionally, when you make a request to that `cloud.vimeo.com` upload_link, only provide the required headers as specified in the documentation.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-approach

Comment: Got ya, thanks !! And what about the actual video file? Do i need to convert it to bytes? and how do i add it to the call?

Comment: In step 1 the video file's size should be provided in bytes, with the header `"upload.size":{size}`. In step 2, you're making a `PATCH` request to that `upload_link` with the raw binary data of your video file.

Comment: If i got it right, the {size} is just an int, that i get by checking the actual file size.
In step 2, i understand that i need to send the raw data, but how? 
As you can see in my UploadPatch method, i'm sending url (upload_link), method (PATCH), headers ({ "Tus-Resumable", "1.0.0" },{ "Upload-Offest", "0" }), body (null), Content Type(application/offset+octet-stream). Where should i add the raw data?

Answer (score 1):

for this may look at the sample code below:-

I am using a nuget library vimeo-dot-net also at https://github.com/mfilippov/vimeo-dot-net, this has a wrapper built around upload, delete etc.

```
       public ActionResult UploadChapterVideoVimeo(HttpPostedFileBase file, string productID = "")
    {
        if (file != null){      
                          var authCheck = Task.Run(async () => await vimeoClient.GetAccountInformationAsync()).Result;
                    if (authCheck.Name != null)
                    {
                        
                        BinaryContent binaryContent = new BinaryContent(file.InputStream, file.ContentType);
                        int chunkSize = 0;
                        int contenetLength = file.ContentLength;
                        int temp1 = contenetLength / 1024;
                        if (temp1 > 1)
                        {
                            chunkSize = temp1 / 1024;
                            chunkSize = chunkSize * 1048576;
                        }
                        else
                        { chunkSize = chunkSize * 1048576; }
                        binaryContent.OriginalFileName = file.FileName;
                        var d = Task.Run(async () => await vimeoClient.UploadEntireFileAsync(binaryContent, chunkSize, null)).Result;
                        vmodel.chapter_vimeo_url = "VIMEO-" + d.ClipUri;
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("ProductBuilder", "Products", new { productId = EncryptedProductID, message = "Successfully Uploaded video", type = 1 });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ProductBuilder", "Products", new { productId = EncryptedProductID, message = "Failed to Uploaded video " + exc.Message, type = 0 });
            }
        }
        return null;        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is VB.Net, but you can change to C#

```
'Imports / use these classes
'Imports System.Net
'Imports Newtonsoft.Json
'Imports System.IO
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
  'Receive the video from File Upload
  If Not IsNothing(fuVideo.PostedFile) Then
    'You will need this for SSL
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or (SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12))
    'Path to save the video Save 
    Dim vFilePath As String = Server.MapPath("App_data/Videos")

    Dim vFileNameAndPath As String = vFilePath & "/" & fuVideo.PostedFile.FileName
    'Save Video
    fuVideo.PostedFile.SaveAs(vFileNameAndPath)

    'Get the size
    Dim vSize As String = New FileInfo(vFileNameAndPath).Length()

    'Vimeo URL
    Dim vVimeURL As String = "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos"

    Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
    wc.Headers.Clear()
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") 'Use your App Code
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4")
    wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

    'txtName is a text box, so you can give a Title to the Video
    Dim vData As String = "{ ""upload"": {""approach"": ""tus"",""size"": """ & vSize & """ }, ""name"" : """ & txtName.Text & """ }"

    Dim vimeoTicket = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(wc.UploadString(vVimeURL, "POST", vData))
    wc.Headers.Clear()
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/offset+octet-stream")
    wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4")
    wc.Headers.Add("Tus-Resumable", "1.0.0")
    wc.Headers.Add("Upload-Offset", "0")
    Dim vupload_link As String = vimeoTicket("upload")("upload_link").Value 'Json from Vimeo has the upload_link
    Dim vResponse As Byte() = wc.UploadFile(vupload_link, "PATCH", vFileNameAndPath)
    Response.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(vResponse)) ' If everething is ok, vResponse is Nothing
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
  ltrErro.Text = "Error"
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: I used WebClient class instead HttpWebRequest, it is simplest to use.

The code is VB.NET and not C#, but it is easy to translate

It receives a file from a web page, saves it in the server and sends to Vimeo.

All the rest code is put in the header or in the body of the command "uploadFile".

According to Vimeo, you must send an initial request for upload with at least the size of the video, then Vimeo returns a json with several informaion but the essential is the upload_link, you must send the video file to that link.